# jQuery not recognizing tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I think I discovered an issue with jquery

It isn't recognizing the tag 'tr#00'

Here is the code in question:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('td#00').html(data);
},
error: function() { 
    $('div#destination').text("Error");
}
```

and

```
<td id="00" height="231" width="260">
                                </td>
```

Can query recognize such a tag?

Comment: Is that the only element on the page with that "id" value ("00")?  Id values have to be unique.

Comment: ID's can't start with a number. Classes can though.

Comment: @sbeliv01 post that as an answer.

Comment: @sbeliv01 -- In HTML5 -- Id's can start with a number

Comment: jQuery still should be able to target it though, even if it isn't correct - http://jsfiddle.net/btLjy/1/. Are you sure your code is correct? You mention `tr#00` in your question but `td#00` in your example.

Comment: `<!doctype html>` Also, to target an id, use the id, not the tagname+id. `$("#00")`

Comment: @user3043594 http://jsbin.com/joxeyoxi/1/edit and VALID HTML! If <td> is not inside table, in that case - it will not be recognized. Try to remove (table, tr) from HTML... :) Invalid HTML -> http://jsbin.com/joxeyoxi/3/edit

Answer (score -1):

You can't start ID name with a number. Rename your ID so that it doesn't start with a number. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp) tutorial.

Note: You can't start class name with a number either.

Comment: I thought number related issues were CSS? I can't get a `.1` to work, but a `.t1` is fine

Comment: hey look, another case where w3schools is wrong and/or out of date.

Comment: There are issues *in CSS* with having non-identifier id or class values, but there are also work-arounds (in CSS).